# How to label jQuery mobile select-menu after adding of input-search in sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am rather new to jquery and ran into the following problem:

I have a main menu and a click on the main menu opens a sub menu with multiple items. Originally, the button that opens the submenu was labeled with the first `<option>` that has an empty value. And this first `<option>` (Countries in my case) with empty value was not listed in the submenu. So far so good.

```
     <script src="mbo_master/javascript/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
     <script src="mbo_master/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#demo-dialog", function (e) {   
    var form = $("<form><input data-type='search'/></form>"),
        page = $(this);

    $(".ui-content, this")
        .prepend(form);

    form.enhanceWithin()
        .on("keyup", "input", function () {
        var data = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("li", page).addClass("ui-screen-hidden")
            .filter(function (i, v) {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(data) > -1;
        }).removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    });

    $(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function () {
        $("#demo-menu li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
        $("input", form).val("");
    }); 

});
```

```
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-input-search {
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
    padding-top: 0;
    max-height: 85vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-selectmenu-list li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-header {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```
    <label for="demo" id="label">Long list:</label>   
    <select name="demo" id="demo" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" class="select">

        <option data-placeholder="true" value="">Countries</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

    </select>
```

After having added a jquery search field on top of the submenu, the first `<option>` with empty value appears in the submenu, what I don´t want.

I can remove it with 
`$("#demo option[value='']").remove();` 
but then the label of the button disappears, too. 
`data-placeholder="true"` didn´t work as well.

I found that the problem is the line
        `$("#demo-menu li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");` in the search-function. 
When it is removed, button-labeling and listing of options work as it should, however, the search function doesn´t work properly, of course.

Is there any possibility that allows labeling of the select-button in the main-menu and listing of items with value only in the submenu?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQM has its own naming convention.

For instance:
the `popup` which will be created to show a short list of `options`, will get its own `id` that is composed by concatenating the *"id"* of the select followed by the keyword *"listbox-popup"*.

the `dialog-page` which will be created to show a long list of `options` exceeding the page height, will get its own `id` that is composed by concatenating the *"id"* of the select followed by the keyword *"dialog"*.

So, after thinking about it, I believe the filterable is needed only when a dialog-page will be displayed, as the choice between `popup` and `dialog-page` is made dynamically, every time the select is opening.

Therefore the code is even simpler, as the JQM built-in `data-filter` option can be used here:

**HTML:**

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page-select-country">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="country-select">Long list:</label>
        <select name="country-select" id="country-select" data-native-menu="false">
          <!-- option empty value will be used as data-placeholder -->
          <option>Choose Your Country</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          ... other oprions...
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#country-select", function(e, ui) {
  var data = $(this).data("mobile-selectmenu"), hide = {"display": "none"};
  data.list
    .attr("data-filter", "true")
    .find("li[data-placeholder='true']").css(hide);
  $(this).on("change", function () {
    var cases = {"page": data.menuPageClose, "overlay": data.headerClose},
        btnClose = cases[data.menuType];
    if ($("option:selected", this).length === 0) {
      btnClose
        .addClass("ui-icon-delete")
        .removeClass("ui-icon-check")
        .css("backgroundColor", "initial");      
    } else {
      btnClose
        .addClass("ui-icon-check")
        .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
        .css("backgroundColor", "#90ee90");
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) {
  var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
  if(ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
    if(!ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable").length) {
      ui.toPage.find(".ui-content").enhanceWithin();
    }
  }
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) {
  var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
  if(ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
    ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
  }
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function(e, ui) {
  var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
  if(ui.prevPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
    data["list"].find("li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    ui.prevPage.find(".ui-filterable input").val("");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks deblocker, the labeling works! But in your solution the search-field is now outside the dialog-box. It should remain on top of the option-list.

Comment: With ```$(document).on("pagecreate", "#country-select-dialog", function(e, ui)``` instead of ```$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-select-country", function(e, ui)``` in first line of jQuery-function it seems to work when used for the first time. However, after closing and reopening of sub menu, the label is in the option-list again.

Comment: I still discovered a problem: although the label name is no more displayed in the sub menu, it is displayed in the search result list, when it matches the entered letters. Is it possible to remove it from this list, too?

Comment: @Columbus: good catch! Override it with inline style is a quick. fix.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, deblocker! Could you please explain me how to do this in simple words, since I´m not a professional programmer?

Comment: Sorry deblocker, but I didn´t succeed in adding the green check mark here since the JavaScript differs significantly from the other code (where the search field was fixed in popup windows).

Comment: @Columbus: just look there: `$(this).on("change", function () {` if You are still in trouble, feel free to post another question with Your actual code...